# Overriding CDocument OnFileSave()

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How do I do this? If you could please kindly include the code for message map and the function itself, that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

More specifically I am wondering how OnFileSave() links to OnSaveDocument(LPCSTR lpszPathName)
How does OnFileSave get lpszPathName?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to override `OnSaveDocument(...)` it's already a virtual function in CDocument, so your derived class can just declare `virtual BOOL OnSaveDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName);` in it's header, then implement it in the document. Nothing is needed in the message map. OnSaveDocument will be called by the framework as part of OnFileSave which is a handler in the base class for ID_FILE_SAVE. The lpszPathName refers to m_strPathName when called by OnFileSafe, which is set when opening a file or by calling SetPathName. If it's empty when saving, the user is prompted for a file name.

Answer (score 0):

CDocument::OnFileSave is the message handler for the Save menu command. To handle it yourself put this in your document class message map:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_SAVE, OnFileSave)
```

and add your function:

```
void CYOURDOCUMENT::OnFileSave()
{
CDocument::OnFileSave();
}
```

To see everything it does put a breakpoint in your function and start single-stepping.